# Excel 2007 - Trying to copy and paste values only by default and delete the source in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to find a way to use cut and paste special, values only. From what I read so far, it seems it's not possible.  So the other way I found is to use vba, to copy and paste values only on my spreadsheet.  Now I would like to add a line to delete the source after it as been pasted.

here is what i found so far (sorry I am completely new to vba).

```
Sub PasteAsValue()
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

then under the macro name "PasteAsValue" I enter a shortcut key ctrl+v

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Right Click - Paste Values doesn't work, you want a key shortcut?

Comment: Do you want to update the VBA code to delete the source after the paste operation?

Comment: Hi Brucewayne, problem is it's a shared worksheet and people keep messing up the format when they use the cut and paste method..if there is a way to use cut and paste values only I dont know how.  With the copy paste special (values only) it works great but we have to manually clear the content of the cell being pasted in another cell.  Any tips will be appreciated.  I'm sure is an easy way that I am just not seeing.

Comment: Prasanna thats exactly what I am looking for ;-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, would using the cut command, instead of copy work? Then your VBA would work for the pasting command?

Comment: jrichall sadly it doesn't, was hoping it would as well :-)

Comment: Just in case it is not clear I am looking for a way to clear the values in the cell with the marching ants around it after I copied that data to another cell.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have not specified which Row/Rows to Cut, Paste and Delete, therefore I've assumed the Source and Destination Row. Better you alter the Range as you need.*

```
Sub CutPaste()    

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Range("A10").Select
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Range("A2").EntireRow.Delete

    End Sub
```

*Hope this help you.*